# Is it pointless to scale your containers in the same physical server?

Tags: docker, containers, autoscaling, scaling

This is a question I couldn't find an answer Googling, maybe the terms I should search are different.

Suppose you have a containerized app, NGINX Container, PHP Container and DB Container.

You need to increment processing so you understand that you need to scale the PHP Container.

But to do this, you need one more server per different container?

Because, I think that if you scale your container is because you ran out of processing power in the first server, right?

Answer (score 1):

Depends. Depends whether your server is powerfull enough.

if you run a number of simulatd 4 cores on a 21 core machine, then most liekly you can ramp them all up to 8 cores and still not use up the server.

But if you run a number of 4 core machiens on a 4 core server, and th CPU tops out - yes, you need another / more power full server.